# Modifying RequestBody in spring gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to modify the requestBody before routing it to given URI . Based on docs i am using

**org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory** to modify the body .  On starting my server , server failed to start with below error
Reason: The elements [spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0].modifyrequestbody.class] were left unbound.\n\nAction:\n\nUpdate your application's configuration\n","context":"default"}

Below is the sample filter and Rewrite function

```
@Slf4j
public class SomeFilter implements GatewayFilter {

    private final ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory factory;

    public RedirectionFilter(ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        
        ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config cfg = new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config();
        cfg.setContentType("application/json");
        cfg.setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, new MyRewriteFunction());


        factory.apply(cfg).filter(exchange, chain);

        // Continue the filter chain
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Below is rewrite function

```
@Slf4j
public class MyRewriteFunction implements RewriteFunction<String, String> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<String> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, String s) {
        
        
            try {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                HelloObject obj = objectMapper.readValue(s, HelloObject.class);
                String newBody = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj.getData());
                return Mono.just(newBody);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* error parsing values to json, do something else */
                log.error("Error while parsing body", e);
            }
        }
        return Mono.just(s);
    }
}
```

Below is yaml

```
      routes:
        - id: order-route-1
          uri: http://localhost:8999/
          predicates:
            - Path=/some/path1
            - Method=POST
          filters:
            - ModifyRequestBody:
                class: com.xyz.filters.SomeFilter
                value: application/json, application/xml
                enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few things with your code:

1. `SomeFilter` class is not needed, just use the `ModifyRequestBody` directly from your route configuration. If you really need it to achieve something that can't be done with `ModifyRequestBody`, you have to make it a bean by adding @Component.
2. The syntax for your YAML configuration is incorrect. Please refer the following revised version:

```yaml
      routes:
        - id: order-route-1
          uri: http://localhost:8999/
          predicates:
            - Path=/some/path1
            - Method=POST
          filters:
            - name: ModifyRequestBody
              args:
                inClass: com.xyz.filters.OldType
                outClass: com.xyz.filters.NewType
                rewriteFunction: com.xyz.filters.MyRewriteFunction
                contentType: application/json
```

- `inClass`: The fully qualified class name that represents the structure of the original request body.
- `outClass`: The fully qualified class name that represents the structure of the modified request body.
- `rewriteFunction`: Refers to the fully qualified class name that implements the RewriteFunction interface for transforming the request body from OriginalType to NewType.
- `contentType` (optional): Specify this parameter when you want to change the content type of the request.

Let's assume that you're converting `OldType` to `NewType`, below would be the implementation for `RewriteFunction`:

```java
public class MyRewriteFunction implements RewriteFunction<OldType, NewType> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<NewType> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, OldType originalRequest) {
     
        NewType modifiedRequest = modifyRequest(originalRequest);
        return Mono.just(modifiedRequest);
    }
}
```